# Register Serilog with Autofac

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac, serilog

How to use Microsoft.Extensions.Logging logger with Autofac & Serilog?

Exception:

Inner Exception 1:
DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'TransactionStorage.Core.StorageService' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[TransactionStorage.Core.StorageService] logger' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[TransactionStorage.Core.StorageService])'.

Registry:

```
using Autofac;
using AutofacSerilogIntegration;

var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .CreateLogger();

builder.RegisterLogger(logger);
```

Caller class:

```
private readonly ILogger<StorageService> _logger;

public StorageService(ILogger<StorageService> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you have to mix autofac with Microsoft DI;

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .CreateLogger();

IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddLogging(r =>
{
    r.AddSerilog(logger);
});

var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.Populate(services);
```

Comment: (as you found out) : You have to remember (always) that in the "new world" (dot-net-core)...any concrete (SerialLog, NLog, etc) is an ** implementation ** of Microsoft.Logging...not a "replacement".

Comment: I never thought otherwise, though I expected Autofac to handle logger registration itself w/o resorting to IServiceCollection

Comment: Understood.    we can change "as you found out" to "future readers of this answer and comments"      :)